# ajax - Why does when i call the .php file, the jquery function of it doesnt work

Tags: php, ajax, datetimepicker

I have this in my `<head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/date.js"></script>
```

all of it is vital to run the date time picker which is this.

```
<span><input id="datepicker" style="width:64px;outline:none;border:transparent;" type="text" > </span>
```

Yeah sure thing, it works. but whenever i am calling the whole .php of it and it display to the page. it doesnt work. here is my ajax code.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function get_bookextt(user_id) {
     var request = $.ajax({
                         url: "getbookext.php",
                         type: "POST",
                         data: {'user_id': user_id},
                         dataType: "html"
                    });
     request.done(function(msg) {
          $("#get_bookext").html(msg);            
     });
     request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
          alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
     });
}
</script>
```

So i will recap my question in case i didnt explain it very well. that getbookext.php is working just fine, but whenever i am calling it from another page, the date time picker doesnt work anymore.

EDITED:
The page i am calling it from also have the seam `<head>` could it be the problem?

Comment: Can we see your PHP code aswell?

Comment: Define _"another page"_, and what is the URI for `getbookext.php`? is it `yourdomain.com/getbookext.php`? If so, try adding a slash : `url: '/getbookext.php'`, because the url value is relative

Comment: If you are loading elements that contain datepickers through ajax, you need to bind the datepicker to these elements manually when the ajax call completes. As far as I know you cannot use event delegation to bind datepickers.

Comment: @Daan sure thing bro, can you give me a site where i can paste my code?

Comment: @Elias Van, i am currently working just in localhost, the passing of the page is just fine, but whenever it is already called, the date time picker doesnt work.

Comment: @WTFZane edit your question.

Comment: @WTFZane: How is your js function called, and when? `$("#get_bookext").html(msg);` seems to suggest you're replacing a lot of DOM elements, if `get_bookextt` is called by an event handler for an event of one of the elements you've replaced, you might want to switch to delegation instead of direct binding, that's almost always the better option anyway

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Can u suggest a topic on how I can google that?

Comment: @EliasVanOotgem, why does jeroen, that I cannot use delegation when you are stating that I should use delegation?

Comment: @jeroen: why wouldn't you be able to use delegation? You can listen for events at some higher level (container, body or document... wherever), listen for [DOM mutation events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Common.2FW3C_events), and initialize the datepicker using that

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem As far as I am aware you always need to bind the datepicker manually using the `.datepicker()` method, I don't know of any way to do that using the standard `$(el).on(..., child_el, ...)` method. That's what I mean with "manually" but of course you can put the method itself in any delegated event handler so perhaps we are actually talking about the same thing...

Comment: @jeroen, I guess we are, to the OP: [this is what I had in mind](http://jsfiddle.net/XcBGb/), more or less JIT initialization is explained (pro's and cons) [here](http://elijahmanor.com/dont-initialize-all-the-things-in-jquery-ready/)